How to connect mssql database to wso2 server as secondary user store
Here is an example how to connect mysql
Connection URL :jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{Database_Name}?useSSL=false
Driver Name : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Connection name: root
password: mysql password
I want credentials like this
I have tried different connection url for mssql but it was not working and i don't the username and password for mssql. So how to implment in new version os wso2

mssql != mysql, what are you trying to do?

I am trying to connect mssql as secondary database.

In this doc, you can find multiple ways to connect to a MSSQL database. However, if you want to configure a Secondary Userstore with JDBC and MSSQL, it is required to know the username and password to connect to the database. Do you have any other authentication mechanism to connect to your MSSQL instance in your environment? If so, please update the question with relevant information.
